# If $G$ is an algebraic group of adjoint type, is $\alpha_s^\vee(-1)=1$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, root-systems, coxeter-groups

Suppose $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group of adjoint type. If $(W,S)$ is the Coxeter system and $s\in S$, and $\alpha_s$ is a simple root with corresponding coroot $\alpha_s^\vee$, is it true that $\alpha_s^\vee(-1)=1$?

I know $\alpha_s^\vee(-1)$ is always an element of order dividing $2$ in the torus, but I am wondering if they are easier to deal with in the case where $G$ is of adjoint type.

Comment: Look at the co-charactre in $SL_2$ and that doesnot satisfy what you have written. Now one can embed $SL_2 \hookrightarrow SL_3$ as the first $2 \times 2$ block followed by the map to the adjoint group of $SL_3$. Note that this composite map doesnot have any kernel over $\mathbb{C}$. Thus you can find a co-character such that it doesnot satisfy your condition.